# Phonegap debugging remote user

Tags: java, javascript, android, debugging, cordova

A user is complaining about a problem that I can not reproduce in any emulator or VM.

How can I determine and fix the bug?

The application does not crash or show any error message but it does not function as it suppose to. I have no access to the users phone. Also I can not tell if the problem is caused by Javascript or Java.

Comment: What is the software doing?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik That should not be relevant for the problem but it's loading date from a webpage an displays time-based local notifications. Problem is that only the first reminder is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is running Android, you could have them provide the logcat dump using an app such as [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat)